# Record multiple mics on one line

Tags: learning, recording, drums, microphones, drum-kits

Is there a way I can connect two or more headset microphones to a single jack to record drums?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82434/discussion-on-question-by-dreambegin-record-drums-using-earphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Still not sure I understand the question, but you can use headphone splitters to make the headsets all go into one jack.

Personally I think that you will get much better quality and more ease of use by recording each part (vocals, guitar, drums) separately and mixing them. If you listen to the song with earbuds while recording then you won't need to worry about playing at the wrong tempo.

Comment: the splitter have two jacks one for output and one for input  i need two input jacks so i can connect two earphones and use there mics.

Comment: @dreamBegin well you'll either have to buy a splitter or record each part separately, which  is the usual way to do it

Comment: Sounds true, So the answer to my question is No.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can use a splitter.

Comment: i think there's a misunderstanding here, Splitter have multiple output not input i think @Aric

Comment: The jacks work as both inputs and outputs. If you plug the splitter into your line in or microphone jack and then plug the headsets into the splitter it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use earphones as microphones.

To use earphones as mic on your PC:

Plug your earphones into the mic jack, which will be called "audio
            input" or "line-in"

Open the sound control panel in your settings. 
            On Windows 10, go to the Sound settings and the Recording tab.

Tap on the earphones and watch the green bar.  If the green bar
        jumps
            then you have signal.  If you don't you may have to fiddle a bit.

If you have signal then set your settings to default and you're good
        to
            go.

Comment: Based on the comments to the question the OP wants to use multiple mics (headphones) to individually mic up each drum.

Comment: @b3ko OP says  " To elaborate more forget about drums suppose i have a guitar, a mobile phone and two earphones. what i will do is put one earphones mic near my guitar to record guitar audio and one near my face to record my voice and i just don't know how to connect both the two pieces to make a single input that the mobile is going to reord."   Earphones have two. :-)

Comment: But then he also said "as i mention earphones for recording that clearly means i want to record audio from the earphone's mic"

Comment: I think he wants to use the mics on multiple earbuds as if they were "real" mics.

Comment: Sorry for being late to the discussion, Thank you for your time @pro but i already know how to record audio using a earphone whether from a mic or from pc my question was how can i connect multiple earphone to a single device like cellphone or pc.